# Glib regex for matching whole word?

Tags: regex, pcre, glib, vala

For matching a whole word, the regex `\bword\b` should suffice. Yet the following code always returns 0 matches

```
try {
        string pattern = "\bhtml\b";
        Regex wordRegex = new Regex (pattern, RegexCompileFlags.CASELESS, RegexMatchFlags.NOTEMPTY);
        MatchInfo matchInfo;
        string lineOfText = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">";

        wordRegex.match (lineOfText, RegexMatchFlags.NOTEMPTY, out matchInfo);
        stdout.printf ("Match count is: %d\n", matchInfo.get_match_count ());
    } catch (RegexError regexError) {
        stderr.printf ("Regex error: %s\n", regexError.message);
    }
```

This should be working as testing the **\bhtml\b** pattern returns one match for the provided string in testing engines. But on this program it returns 0 matches. Is the code wrong? What regex in Glib would be used to match a whole word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to escape the backslash too:

```
try {
        string pattern = "\\bhtml\\b";
        Regex wordRegex = new Regex (pattern, RegexCompileFlags.CASELESS, RegexMatchFlags.NOTEMPTY);
        MatchInfo matchInfo;
        string lineOfText = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">";

        wordRegex.match (lineOfText, RegexMatchFlags.NOTEMPTY, out matchInfo);
        stdout.printf ("Match count is: %d\n", matchInfo.get_match_count ());
    } catch (RegexError regexError) {
        stderr.printf ("Regex error: %s\n", regexError.message);
    }
```

Output:

```
Match count is: 1
```

[**Demo**](https://tio.run/##dVJdS8MwFH33V1wLQgtb4tjb5gTtKg72xRbRQWHENesKbVLSOzsRf3vt19opmJfcm3vPPeck@eAhzzLUn/B1BfVKUAfSh5gjCi1hBIbrvh8wCvPNGDZtK@GLE6RKe1U0AinS@tSswZ0qt1UUB6F4CrmfEPth7Uyd9bquzTjuDlVlvmDObMk2VktSVidyryA6R8O/QsNAisWeiRMWWu@uxwubbZYOFJJh@fI4ndjgGl1KX/s2pWM2hrdnNptCj9wC01wmAQZK8pBSZ@4aeesBMR5QmqYpSftEaZ@yFT0V43oFvA67eIElHnqucZ9fT6OuuRlSSgez1fm/9Q6oI7ZerUuzXl4icW4Z92AaJRh26igRgmQAN54rjU4LJb7AbZltqybTqqd9w64SVIpwtFYadBNav36CJ7RuOavHFUVbTpiUhC2SRCJJuC/ONFn2Aw)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code with [regular expression literals](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Regular_Expression_Literals):

```
Regex regex = /\bhtml\b/i;
```

You don't have to quote backslashes in the regular expression literal syntax. (Front slashes would be problematic though.)

Full example:

```
void test_match (string text, Regex regex) {
    MatchInfo match_info;
    if (regex.match (text, RegexMatchFlags.NOTEMPTY, out match_info)) {
        stdout.printf ("Match count is: %d\n", match_info.get_match_count ());
    }
    else {
        stdout.printf ("No match");
    }
}

int main () {
    Regex regex = /\bhtml\b/i;
    test_match ("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>", regex);

    return 0;
}
```